# Proxy a RESTful service using SOAP with WSO2 ESB

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-esb

We want to proxy a RESTful web service with SOAP.

The REST service uses the GET method and accepts inputs via query parameters. It produces a resource of type application/csv.

Does WSO2 ESB/Synapse support such a scenario, and is there an example available?

**Example Request**

SOAP Proxy Request:

```
<request>
  <fromDate>2012-01-01</fromDate>
  <toDate>2012-12-31</toDate>
</request>
```

REST Endpoint Request:

```
http://localhost/person?fromDate=2012-01-01&toDate=2012-12-31
```

**Example Response**

REST Endpoint Response

```
"Name","Age","Sex"
"Geoff","22","Male"
```

SOAP Proxy Response

```
<person>
  <name>Geoff</name>
  <age>22</age>
  <sex>Male</sex>
<person>
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you correctly, you want to expose a REST service as a SOAP service, so that SOAP clients can access your REST service through the ESB?

If that is the case, it is possible :) You should check out sample 152 from these: http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB451/Proxy+Service+Samples

It'll explain how you take a SOAP request and pass it to a REST backend and then transform the REST response into a SOAP response.

EDIT: Here's a sample configuration on how to do what you asked in the comments, hopefully it will get you started :)

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="RESTProxy" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>

         <!-- We set the HTTP Method we want to use to make the REST request here -->
         <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="GET" scope="axis2"/>

         <!-- This is where the magic happens, for what you want i.e. mapping SOAP "params" to REST query param's --> 
         <property name="messageType" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" scope="axis2"/>

         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <!-- This is the RESTful URL we are going to query, like the one in the ESB example 152 -->
               <address uri="http://localhost/person" />
            </endpoint>
         </send>

      </inSequence>

      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

Then the SOAP request you make to the ESB should be something like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
    <person>
        <fromDate>2012-01-01</fromDate>
        <toDate>2012-12-31</toDate>
    </person>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Many thanks, the example is very helpful. However we are still wondering - how can we convert the SOAP xml parameters into query parameters for our REST call? Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Hope This will be very helpful you to understand of SOAP Client and REST Service communication

http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB460/Using+REST+with+a+Proxy+Service#UsingRESTwithaProxyService-SOAPClientandRESTService

Answer (score 0):

You can use class mediator to extract the SOAP parameters using XPATH. Than build the REST URL and send it back to IN sequence flow.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** you need to get the value from SOAP PROXY

**2.** you need to store it in a local variable

**3.** you need to pass the value to the REST SERVICE using Query Parameters

**4.** you need to format the response from REST Service to an SOAP Format

The SOAP Request will be,

`<request>
<fromDate>2012-01-01</fromDate>
<toDate>2012-12-31</toDate>
</request>`

You can store the value from SOAP PROXY Request as,

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="RESTProxy" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true><target>
  <inSequence>
      <property name="fromDate" expression="//fromDate" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
      <property name="toDate" expression="//toDate" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

Then you can pass the values to the REST Service by,

```
<send>
     <endpoint>  
           <http method="GET" uri-template="http://localhost/person?fromDate=={get-property('fromDate')}&amp;toDate={get-property('toDate')}"/>  
    </endpoint>
</send>  
</inSequence>
```

Then You can Format the Response using **PayloadFactory** mediator,

```
<outSequence>  
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">     
      <format>
               <person>
                      <Name>$1</Name>
                      <Age>$2</Age>
                      <Sex>$3</Sex>
                </person>
        </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.Name"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.Age"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.Sex"/>
                </args>
 </payloadFactory>
     <send/>
  </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
  </proxy>
```

So the Response of Proxy will be,

```
<person>
  <name>Geoff</name>
  <age>22</age>
  <sex>Male</sex>
<person>
```